# I have the methods, but need program code for Grade enum

Tags: java, methods, constructor, enums, instance-variables

I need to write a Java enumeration LetterGrade that represents letter grades A through F, including plus and minus grades.
Now this is my enumeration code:

```
public enum Grade {
A(true),
A_PLUS(true),
A_MINUS(true),
B(true),
B_PLUS(true),
B_MINUS(true),
C(true),
D(true),
E(true),
F(false);

final private boolean passed;

private Grade(boolean passed) {
    this.passed = passed;
}

public boolean isPassing() {
    return this.passed;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    final String name = name();
    if (name.contains("PLUS")) {
        return name.charAt(0) + "+"; 
    }
    else if (name.contains("MINUS")) {
        return name.charAt(0) + "-"; 
    }
    else {
        return name;
    }
}
```

What I am confused about is writing the main program. I think it could be quite straightforward but I have no clue on how to start it.
I don't want the whole code. Just a few lines to give me a head start. The rest I will try to figure out on my own.

Comment: What should your main programm do?

Comment: Okay. It needs to calculate if a student has passed or failed. So surely I would need to define in which % mark the letterGrade falls in.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I have no idea, what you are looking for.

Comment: The main program will use the methods in the enum to determine if a student has pass or failed.

Comment: Your first problem is that It seems that you are asking for source code without even telling what you want anything to do... The second problem is that this site is not meant to generate source code for you. It is a little more meant to help out with specific problems that you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have a Student class that looks like this:

```
class Student {

    protected Grade grade = null;  

    public Student(Grade g) {
        this.grade = g; 
     }
}
```

Then you simply add a method in this class calling the `isPassing` method from your `enum`:

```
public boolean isPassing() {
    if (this.grade != null) 
        return this.grade.isPassing();
    return false;
}
```

This is supposing the `passed` boolean in `Grade` are correctly set and are invariant.